# Examples of trivial graph properties.

Tags: graph-theory

In "A Topological Approach to Evasiveness" by Kahn and Saks, it is state that:

> ... every graph property that is monotone (preserved by the addition of edges) and nontrivial (holds for some but not all graphs) has complexity $\Omega(v^2)$

I feel kind of silly for asking this, but besides for concluding that a graph $G$ is in fact a graph, what kind of property is trivial? My first thought is 4-colorability, except that it requires the graph to be planar, and planarity is evasive...

Furthermore, are there any nontrivial trivial properties (ones that require fairly involved proofs)?

I've been trying to search for an answer to this, but google keeps telling me what the definition of a trivial graph is, which is not what I want. Sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: @Joffan: Nice. Please feel free to post that as answer and I will accept! Thanks! (Although, I might wait a bit, it would be nice to see if there some exceptionally nontrivial trivial properties...)

Comment: Hah, yes, definitely give time for more creative answers.

Comment: @Theophile: Some graphs are connected, and some aren't. So I don't think it is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the definition of trivial properties given, "the sum of the vertex degrees is twice the number of edges" holds for all graphs.